# error while converting access to oracle select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to convert my access statement to sql developer and getting more record then i should and it ask me to **enter substitution variable for B***  please see both queries can someone help

**QUERY CREATED IN ORACLE**

```
SELECT  
cast(vw_GE_SUMQry.year as varchar2(4)) || '-' || substr(cast(vw_GE_SUMQry.year+1 as varchar(4)),3) YEARF
gems_cmn_location.LOCATION_ENG,
vw_ge_sumqry.srce,
GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES.industry,
vw_gdp_currentqry.method,
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value,
vw_GE_SUMQry.ge_expend/vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value*0.0001 AS GEGDP
FROM gems_cmn_location INNER JOIN (vw_gdp_currentqry
INNER JOIN vw_GE_SUMQry ON vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC = vw_GE_SUMQry.LOC AND vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR = vw_GE_SUMQry.YEAR
INNER JOIN GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES ON vw_gdp_currentqry.IND = GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES.IND) 
ON gems_cmn_location = vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND<>'F&B';
```

**QUERY THAT I NEEDED TO CREATE FROM**

```
 SELECT 
[GE_SUMQry].[YEAR] & "-" & Right([GE_SUMQry].[YEAR]+1,2) AS YEARF,
LOCATION.LOCATION_ENG, 
GE_SUMQry.SRCE, 
INDUSTRIES.INDUSTRY, 
[GDP_$CurrentQry].METHOD, 
[GDP_$CurrentQry].[$CURRENT], 
[ge_expend]/[$current]*0.0001 AS [GE%GDP]
FROM LOCATION INNER JOIN (([GDP_$CurrentQry] INNER JOIN GE_SUMQry ON ([GDP_$CurrentQry].LOC = GE_SUMQry.LOC) AND ([GDP_$CurrentQry].YEAR = GE_SUMQry.YEAR)) INNER JOIN INDUSTRIES ON [GDP_$CurrentQry].IND = INDUSTRIES.IND) ON LOCATION.LOC = [GDP_$CurrentQry].LOC
WHERE ((([GDP_$CurrentQry].IND)<>"F&B"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle uses `&` as a placeholder for bind variables, so it needs to be escaped.  You can either call `SET ESCAPE ON` first, and change `'F&B'` to `'F\&B'`, or if it's not possible to call SET, then you can just use `'F' || '&' || 'B'`.

So, either:

```
SET ESCAPE ON;
SELECT  
cast(vw_GE_SUMQry.year as varchar2(4)) || '-' || substr(cast(vw_GE_SUMQry.year+1 as varchar(4)),3) YEARF
gems_cmn_location.LOCATION_ENG,
vw_ge_sumqry.srce,
GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES.industry,
vw_gdp_currentqry.method,
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value,
vw_GE_SUMQry.ge_expend/vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value*0.0001 AS GEGDP
FROM gems_cmn_location INNER JOIN (vw_gdp_currentqry
INNER JOIN vw_GE_SUMQry ON vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC = vw_GE_SUMQry.LOC AND      vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR = vw_GE_SUMQry.YEAR
INNER JOIN GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES ON vw_gdp_currentqry.IND = GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES.IND) 
ON gems_cmn_location = vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND<>'F&B';
```

or:

```
SELECT  
cast(vw_GE_SUMQry.year as varchar2(4)) || '-' || substr(cast(vw_GE_SUMQry.year+1 as varchar(4)),3) YEARF
gems_cmn_location.LOCATION_ENG,
vw_ge_sumqry.srce,
GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES.industry,
vw_gdp_currentqry.method,
vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value,
vw_GE_SUMQry.ge_expend/vw_gdp_currentqry.current_value*0.0001 AS GEGDP
FROM gems_cmn_location INNER JOIN (vw_gdp_currentqry
INNER JOIN vw_GE_SUMQry ON vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC = vw_GE_SUMQry.LOC AND      vw_gdp_currentqry.YEAR = vw_GE_SUMQry.YEAR
INNER JOIN GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES ON vw_gdp_currentqry.IND = GEMS_CMN_INDUSTRIES.IND) 
ON gems_cmn_location = vw_gdp_currentqry.LOC
WHERE vw_gdp_currentqry.IND<>'F' || '&' || 'B';
```